# Apply Lambda on 2 dataframe columns in one line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, multiple-columns

```
r_c = 'newyork sanfrancisco losangeles'.split()

def my_is_r_c(c):
    return c.replace(' ', '').lower() in r_c

train['is_r_c'] = train['c_o'].apply(lambda x: 1 if my_is_r_c(x) else 0)
train['is_r_c'] = train['c_d'].apply(lambda x: 1 if my_is_r_c(x) else 0)
```

Hi guys

Is there a way to apply the lambda for both columns ['c_o'] and ['c_d'], in only one line?

thx in advance

Comment: Is it a typo, that you use the same name for the result column in both lines? The first assignment based on `c_o` would have no effect at all, as it is overwrttien by the second line, or do you rather want to have the result rows "ORed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that useing `applymap` like this:

```
df[['is_r_c', 'is_r_d']]= df[['c_o', 'c_d']].applymap(lambda x: 1 if my_is_r_c(x) else 0)
```

In case you want the columns combined, and there in fact is only one result column, which should contain 1 if your function evaluates to 1 for at least one of the columns, you can do that with a small variation like this:

```
df[['is_r_c']]= df[['c_o', 'c_d']].applymap(lambda x: 1 if my_is_r_c(x) else 0).max(axis='columns')
```

Comment: thank you all for the great help. this one did it: df[['is_r_c']]= df[['c_o', 'c_d']].applymap(lambda x: 1 if my_is_r_c(x) else 0).max(axis='columns') as i need to put it in the same column

Comment: @joao thank you for your feedback. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `df.filter`:

```
df.filter(regex='c_[od]').apply(lambda x: 1 if my_is_r_c(x) else 0)
```

Comment: hi, AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'
doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the function like this:

```
# use of `isin` allows passing a series
def my_is_rc(c):
    return c.replace(' ','').isin(r_c).astype(int)

# apply along the columns    
train[['is_rc','is_rd']] = train[['c_o','c_d']].apply(my_is_rc)
```

Or just forget about `apply` and:

```
train[['is_rc','is_rd']] = train[['c_o','c_d']].isin(r_c).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by creating **two** (instead of one as in your question) new columns and using fancy indexing on the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

train = pd.DataFrame(dict(c_o=[1, 2, 3], c_d=[4, 5, 6]))
train
train[['x_1', 'x_2']] = train[['c_o', 'c_d']].apply(lambda x: x**2)
train
```

Cheers.